# Audio interface huge blast of distortion every couple seconds to minute

Tags: windows-10, audio, desktop-computer, audio-output, distortion

for the past year I've been having trouble with audio through audio interfaces. Scarlette solo 2nd gen and then a Scarlette solo 3rd gen (one after the other). Every couple seconds when sound is going through the device distortion surges my headphones for a second. It has made music unlistenable.

I've messed with Windows Power Plan adjusting settings in favor of the device, tried different buffer sizes, tried different headphones, sample rates match on windows and focusrite conrol, drivers reinstalled, and any audio software that could have been causing the issue has been purged. ect.

I've ran a latencyMon test, ill include the results if someone wants to see them.

(My mic is also occasionally effected but has only happened once or thrice)

Comment: From the description, there may be a sound level normalizer (compressor) in the audio chain misbehaving. Remove all audio devices and add each back one at a time until you find the cause.